# SQL - Multiple counts as appended columns

Tags: sql

I have a query:

```
select e.Owner as 'Owner', COUNT(l.EnquiryID) as 'Total Sales Lines'
from DayBookQuoteLines l, DayBookEnquiries e
where l.EnquiryID = e.EnquiryID
and MONTH(e.enquirydate) = 8 and YEAR(e.enquirydate) = 2012 
group by e.Owner
```

This returns the owner column which contains a name and a total column, but i wish to have two more columns where i apply an additional filter and count again, adding in:

```
l.LostStatusId =2
```

and

```
l.LostStatusId =3
```

So i'll be left with a result set that looks like something like this:

```
Owner      Total Lines    Total Sold    Total Lost    

Person1    124            112           12
```

I cant seem to get the query right. I'm attempting to use sub-selects but am obviously missing something, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might conditionally count records by adding one when condition is satisfied.

```
select e.Owner as 'Owner', 
       COUNT(l.EnquiryID) as 'Total Sales Lines',
       sum(case when l.LostStatusId = 2 then 1 end) TotalSold,
       sum(case when l.LostStatusId = 3 then 1 end) TotalLost
  from DayBookQuoteLines l
 inner join DayBookEnquiries e
    on l.EnquiryID = e.EnquiryID
 where MONTH(e.enquirydate) = 8 
   and YEAR(e.enquirydate) = 2012 
 group by e.Owner
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the various totals

```
select e.owner, LostStatusID , COUNT(l.EnquiryID)
from DayBookQuoteLines l
    inner join DayBookEnquiries e  
    on l.EnquiryID = e.EnquiryID    
group by owner, LostStatusID with rollup
```

If you want to arrange it horizontally, you need a PIVOT. This depends on your variety of SQL.

```
select owner, [2]+[3] as total, [2],[3]
from 
(
    select e.owner, LostStatusID , l.EnquiryID
    from DayBookQuoteLines l
        inner join DayBookEnquiries e  
        on l.EnquiryID = e.EnquiryID    

) v
    pivot
(count(enquiryid) for LostStatusID in ([2],[3])) p
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to write without seeing the schema, but have you tried this:

```
select 
    e.Owner as 'Owner', 
    COUNT(l.EnquiryID) as 'Total Sales Lines'
    count(select count(a.salesMade) from DayBookQuoteLines where month=MONTH(e.enquirydate)) as totalSold,
    count(select count(a.lostSales) from DayBookQuoteLines where month=MONTH(e.enquirydate)) as totalLost
from 
    DayBookQuoteLines l, 
    DayBookEnquiries e
where 
    l.EnquiryID = e.EnquiryID
    and MONTH(e.enquirydate) = 8 
    and YEAR(e.enquirydate) = 2012 
group by e.Owner
```